# How to _get property PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I use magic methods _set, _get:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        array_push($this->groups, $value);
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }
```

And use this like as:

```
// Set
$menu->groupName = 'Регистрация';

// Get
echo $menu->groupName
```

Why `echo $menu->groupName` does not work? it returns nothing. It should return text `'Регистрация'`.

I tried just return in `_get`:

```
return $name;
```

Comment: You don't have `groupName` property.

Comment: See how in `__set()` how you just throw away the `$name` and add the `$value` to an array with no index? Don't do that.

Comment: But I set this `$menu->groupName = 'Регистрация';` and try to get immediately

Comment: `array_push` creates index automaticly

Comment: Think of it like this: You have a cupboard and you're putting your canned goods inside, but first you rip off all the labels and throw them in a fire, but don't worry, you've numbered all the cans so it's fine. Later you go to the cupboard for a can of beets, but the numbers have no relationship to what's inside so now you have to throw everything away and remember that this is a bad idea, unless you don't mind occasionally eating dog food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__set` you process assigning to nonexistent property as adding it's value to array `$this->groups`. This code **does not** create property for you.

When you want to access nonexistent property `__get` works. But in it you want to access `groupName` property, but you didn't create it.

To debug your code, add a line

```
echo'<pre>',print_r($this),'</pre>';
```

to you `__get` method:

```
public function __get($name)
{
    echo'<pre>',print_r($this),'</pre>';    // TODO

    return $this->groups[0];
}
```

You will see that "Регистрация" is there, but it is in `$groups` property.

So, you can either modify `__get` to

```
public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->groups[0];
}
```

as you don't have other values in `$groups`.

Or modify full code:

```
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->groups[$name] = $value;
}

public function __get($name)
{
    return isset($this->groups[$name]) ? $this->groups[$name] : 'NO VALUE';
}
```

Comment: What is difference then comparing this code: `function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; } function get() { return $this->name; }`

Comment: `name` property should be declared at least.

Answer (score 0):

From The [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) on overloading:

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope. The rest of this section will use the terms "inaccessible properties" and "inaccessible methods" to refer to this combination of declaration and visibility.

In short, the properties you want to be handled by your overloading method MUST be either private, protected, or undefined.

Moreover, overloading itself isn't commonly used within PHP. In most cases, it's better to create your own `get()` and `set()` methods, rather than inherit the complexities associated with the overloading magic methods. Even then, custom get/set methods are only practical if you are doing more than just storing the data.

**Where Overloading Makes Sense:**

Overloading is great for security, validation, and data transformation, because it allows you to control the visibility of information within your application.

With overloading you can create variables that:

- Can only be read
- Can only be written to
- Can only be read or written to a certain number of times
- Can be validated before writing
- Can update other variables
- Etc.

Comment: Read again what you just posted and find a string `that have not been declared`.

Comment: Then for what I need set/get if I declare properties :)

Comment: I am taking a guess that he isn't explicitly setting the property's visibility, so by default they are in the "public" visibility.

Comment: @user3573738 They typically are used for allowing access to private or protected protected properties. In most cases, it is usually to make a property either read-only or write-only.

Comment: Overloading isn't commonly used in PHP unless it involves security, and even then it's rare. In other words, you are likely over thinking this and should ditch the overloading methods.

Comment: Setters and Getters are only useful if you are implementing additional functionality beyond 'store and retrieve' eg: validation, access control, etc.

Comment: I dont want to use cutom set/get as: `function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; } function get() { return $this->name; }`